If macroscopic objects weren't in superposition wouldn't they be static?
When we solve the Schrödinger equation we find static solutions for definite energies, and we use those static solutions as a basis for dynamic solutions with uncertain energies.
From this I understand that for a quantum system to be dynamic, it's energy needs to be in superposition. Considering that the macroscopic world we live in is dynamic, doesn't this mean that we necessarily need to be in superposition?

The superposition of any state with itself is the same as the original state.

Yes, any system that is not time independent will not be an eigenstate of the Hamiltonian so it will exist in a superposition of energy eigenstates. In fact this means all systems since for a system to be time independent it must have existed unchanged for an infinite time in the past, which obviously isn't possible in a universe with a finite age.
But this is not surprising, nor is there anything special about it. Every operator has its eigenstates and unless two operators commute their eigenstates will be different. So for example a system in an energy eigenstate is probably not in a momentum eigenstate - all systems will be in a superposition of some observable.

I couldn't say it better. I would also say that for a time-dependent Hamiltonian, a stationary state could not remain stationary along time evolution.

In quantum theory in general the final state of a system in an experiment depends on what happens to all of the possible states during the experiment: this is called quantum interference. For an example, see Section 2 of this paper:
https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9911150
When information is copied out of a system interference is suppressed: this is called decoherence
https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0306072
The objects you see in everyday life have information copied out of them on a scale of space and time that is very small compared to the scales over which they change significantly so interference is negligible on those scales. The relevant states tend to look something like a Gaussian that is very narrow compared to the scales of everyday life. Interference and superposition are not negligible below those scales. So macroscopic objects in general are in a superposition.
